# Issue(s) with HTML code Snippet

Tags: html

I am new to HTML and I was wondering what the issue(s) are with this piece of HTML code and how should I proceed to refactor it to make it secure. Thanks In Advance.

```
<form method="post" action="Login_Account.php">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
</form>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. If you want to send data securely, send it through https. You could also look into adding a [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) check..

Comment: I'm guessing you need a submit button to submit your form, if that's your issue.

Comment: Ok. Well I did say I was a beginner @Magnus Eriksson. There is a security issue with this code, I am just wondering what is it because I am not sure. Is it open to a XSS or CSRF attack at all?

Comment: CSRF, yes, XSS, no. You should handle XSS issues when you display data (since that's when a browser might run injected scripts), not when you receive it.

Comment: It as safe as houses. As you dont actually have a way of submitting it.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you were missing the submit button so I went ahead and added, assuming this is a login form. Personally, I would recommend you [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) the password client side (this means you need to hash it on register), that way in a case of a [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack the attacker does not get a hold of the client's raw password (allowing them to access other services the client uses). Here's an example:

```html
<form method="post" action="Login_Account.php">
<input type="text" name="username"><br>
<input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input value="Login" type="submit" id="loginSubmit">
</form>
<!--Calls the SHA3 Hashing library-->
<script src="https://rawgit.com/emn178/js-sha3/master/build/sha3.min.js"></script>
<!--Javascript to Hash the password-->
<script>
 function hashPass(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //Stop from submit
  pass = document.getElementsByName("password")[0] //Find form element
  pass.value = sha3_512(pass.value); //Hash password in SHA3
  e.target.parentElement.submit(); //Resubmits form
 }
 document.getElementById("loginSubmit").onclick = hashPass //Makes it so when someone clicks the login button it starts the hashing process
</script>
p.s this is going to get an error since this website doesn't have Login_Account.php.
```

Keep in mind you will need to hash the password in the registration process **AND** internally in the PHP code. So if you database is ever leaked your client's passwords are properly protected. In case of a [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), I recommend using a [captcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA). I recommend Google's [ReCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/) which does the job pretty well. There are plenty of tutorials on the internet for setting up ReCaptcha. The security is the best method to build trust with your clients.

**tl;dr**

- Add password hashing which is a way one way encryption so people
  can't see the password if they monitor your connection.
- Add a captcha so people can't make bots.

Comment: Thank You @Some Dinosaur